# render_to_string and //= require tree . issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I use render_to_string on a javascript file that has:

```
//= require tree .
```

Then that line stays there and it doesn't render the other js files that are in the folder.

Here is how I am using render_to_string:

```
tt = render_to_string :file => "app/assets/javascripts/tasks/#{task.title}/thetask.js", :layout => false
```

What other options do I need in there to make it parse the //= require tree . and make the file into a string?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You need to get a version of `thetask.js` that has been passed through the asset pipeline (specifically, Sprockets, as it is responsible for interpreting the `//= require_tree .` lines). What you're doing is asking for the raw `.js` file in the assets directory.

Comment: @Deefour I am trying to send files via JSON instead of downloading files. That content might be stored in a database somewhere.

Comment: @Deefour I will look into how to get the Sprocket version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a different route since I couldn't do what I wanted. I ended up just using JSON and storing two files in the JSON and sent it over to the client.

That solution works for me.